# dyld section not supported after Mojave upgrade

Tags: dyld

I have updated macos to Mojave and after updating the command tools and when I run my c++ program I am getting the following error

dyld: __dyld section not supported in /Users/rameshkolluru/Dropbox/1D_Multiphase_Euler_Equations_FVM/./1D_Multiphase_Euler_solver
Abort trap: 6

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 13):

Are you compiling with the `-pg` option to enable profiling? If yes, try to remove that flag.

Using `-pg` Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.2) still seems to add a `__DATA,__dyld` section to your executable, which dyld in Mojave does not seem to support/accept any more.

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved my issue! Do you have any recommendations on how to use the `-pg` flag in Mojave

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found (or searched for to be honest) a solution to this problem, except that I've handed in a bug report to Apple (rdar://45389681) but no reply from them on this issue yet.

Comment: @julian59189 It seems -pg is officially "unsupported" by LLVM, but luckily there's documentation on how to do profiling: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#profiling-with-instrumentation