# How to use GNU gprof profiler on macOS Mojave?

Tags: c, profiling, macos-mojave, gprof

I want to use GNU gprof that comes with GCC to profile my C program. However, it returns `__dyld section not supported` error when I compile with the `-pg` flag and try to run the program:

```
$ gcc -pg main.c 
$ ./a.out 
dyld: __dyld section not supported in /Users/evgenii/Downloads/c_profile/./a.out
```

This error has been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519907/dyld-section-not-supported-after-mojave-upgrade). Is there a way to use the GNU profiler on macOS Mojave? I'm aware that there are alternative tools for profiling, but I want to use gprof.

Comment: I believe you're not using GCC...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you are right, thanks. When I type `gcc -v` it says it's some weird Apple LLVM thing, not GNU Compiler Collection. WTF?! I want GCC! What should I do now. Install GCC?